Add Scale and Offset to VRT from python
I'm using the python GDAL package to build a VRT containing multiple bands. These bands might have a scale and offset to be applied. Is there any way to add these parameters to the VRT when creating it? I've seen them in the docs but I have been unable to add them using VRTOptions or directly in the BuildVRT methods.
My code is simple, I just iterate the bands from STAC assets and add them to my VRT as follows:
    vrt_options = gdal.BuildVRTOptions(separate=True)
    gdal.BuildVRT(product_vrt_path, band_urls, options=vrt_options)


Not all VRT elements are supported in the gdalbuildvrt command line utility or gdal.BuildVRT function. The Scale and Offset elements aren't.
You could either parse the VRT XML and add those elements manually, or use osgeo.gdal.Band.SetOffset and osgeo.gdal.Band.SetScale.
E.g.
offset = 0.5
scale = 2.0

vrt_options = gdal.BuildVRTOptions(separate=True)
gdal.BuildVRT(product_vrt_path, band_urls, options=vrt_options)

# Open VRT in update mode
ds = gdal.OpenEx(product_vrt_path, gdal.GA_Update)

# Set scale and offset on bands
for i in range(ds.RasterCount):
    rb = ds.GetRasterBand(i+1)
    rb.SetScale(scale)
    rb.SetOffset(offset)
del ds  # close and flush the updated dataset


Thank you! This is what I was looking for, and it might be useful for other parameters!
